# The wordpress website is showing 'w' while it loads and in the footer

Tags: templates

[image: www.madinatulilmacademy.com]

The website www.madinatulilmacademy.com shows letter w while it loads and then in the footer. I Cannot figure out where this 'w' is coming from the developer tools in chrome. I have been trying to debug it for a week. Please help

Comment: check page.php inside your theme

Comment: Please also check your header.php and footer.php

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source you will see a `w` right before the DOCTYPE

```
w
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">   <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>  <html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">   <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>  <html class="ie ie9" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">   <![endif]-->

<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->

<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Check your header.php file as this is likely where the `w` is.